# What's the replacements of override in Rx?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm new to rx and curious about a question: What's the replacement of override in Rx?

For codes I have read about rx, a button is configured like:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateConversation()

    self.naviAvatar.rx.tap
        .debug("naviAvatar tap")
        .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
            print("didTapNaviAvatar")
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

and it works perfect.

However I meet a question that in a subclass I want to silent the button and I don't know how to achieve in rx.

In my previous code, I have following codes:

```swift
class A: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapNaviAvatar(_:)))
        self.naviAvatar.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func didTapNaviAvatar(_ sender: Any) {
            print("didTapNaviAvatar")
        }
    //...
}

class B: A {
    // Silent the method, do nothing.
    override func didTapNaviAvatar(_ sender: Any) {}
    //...
}
```

I came up with an idea that I can reconfigure the `naviAvatar` in `B`'s `viewDidLoad` method. But what if I have number of codes(like 20 lines, including mapping, filtering, configuring) about the button's behavior but I just want to change only one line(like just override the button title on touch down)?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this different from what you had before? Why can’t you just override `didTapNaviMoreButton`?

Answer (score 0):

Weak self isn't needed because there is no delay or async method fired on a tap action. So you can just pass the method and it will trigger the method overridden in class B.

```
 class A: UIViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         naviAvatar.rx.tap
              .debug("naviAvatar tap")
              .subscribe(onNext: didTapNaviMoreButton)
              .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    @objc func didTapNaviAvatar(_ sender: Any) {
        print("didTapNaviAvatar")
    }
}

class A: B {
    override func didTapNaviAvatar(_ sender: Any) {}
}
```